# Compile both x86 and x64 in one configuration?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, 64-bit

Greetings all,

I'm working with a C# solution in VS 2010.  Right now, since I'm targeting AnyCPU, when I want to build my installer, I can just select Release mode and hit build and everything is done for me.  However, pretty soon I'm going to have to add a C++ DLL project to the solution to accomplish some low-level stuff.  To avoid having two different download links for x86 and x64, I'd like to include both builds in my installer.  But, it will be very annoying if I have to have separate configurations for x86 and x64.  I'll have to build one, then the other, then package it up.  Is there some way I can get Visual Studio to compile both the x86 and x64 builds of the C++ project as part of Release mode?

Comment: See also:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574075/use-a-single-visual-studio-solution-to-build-both-x86-and-x64-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I found a solution.  Just make two projects, one for x86 build and one for x64 build, referencing the same source files.  It's ugly, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will have to manually edit the proj files to ensure that the msbuild instructions are correct. I suspect it's not a hard job.

Comment: I've tried editing the solution file's `GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution` section; this doesn't work.  It just compiles the first configuration listed and ignores any subsequent listings.

Answer (score 0):

Just add executing command to build such configuration in PostBuild event of C++ DLL project. Use macroses and help of "devenv /?".

AFAIR e.g.:

```
devenv $(SolutionName) /project $(ProjectName) /ProjectConfig "Release|x64"
```