# Use a single Visual Studio solution to build both x86 and x64 at the same time for C++/CLI project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, c++-cli

As a follow-up to this question:
[Use a single Visual Studio solution to build both x86 and x64 at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574075/use-a-single-visual-studio-solution-to-build-both-x86-and-x64-at-the-same-time)

I'm using the technique in the accepted answer for C# projects and it works great.  **Is there a way to do the same thing for C++/CLI project (.vcxproj)?**  Using that technique doesn't seem to work (the "BeforeBuild" and "AfterBuild" targets seem to be ignored).

I'd even be okay with having the task be executed from the Before/AfterBuild Target of another C# project in the solution:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <MSBuild Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x64' " Projects="MyCPPCLIProject.vcxproj" Properties="Platform=x86;" />
</Target>
```

When I do this, I get the following error (even though the project is in the solution):

```
C:\VS\MyCSProj.csproj(1773,5): error MSB3202: The project file "MyCPPCLIProject.vcxproj" was not found.
```

Comment: Try specifying something more for the project filename. Include the path relative to the .sln file, or use `$(SolutionDir)` as part of the full path.

Comment: Just use Build + Batch Build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying something more for the project filename. Use `$(SolutionDir)` as part of the full path.

Comment: Specifying the full path in the c# project worked for me, thanks.